# Why the doors lock state override and set to false when running the game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

It's working fine when the game is already running. I can change each door lock state. But before running the game is I set one or more of the doors to be locked( Checked set the flag to true ) and then running the game it's changing all the doors back to false unlocked.

I want that if I set the doors lock state also before running the game that it will keep this changes when the game is running.

The first script is with one line only:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class DoorsLockManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<HoriDoorManager> Doors = new List<HoriDoorManager>();
}
```

The second script control the doors:

```
using UnityEditor;

[CustomEditor(typeof(DoorsLockManager))]
public class DoorsLockManagerEditor : Editor
{
    DoorsLockManager _manager;

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        _manager = (DoorsLockManager)target;

        base.OnInspectorGUI();

        if (_manager.Doors.Count <= 0)
            return;
        for (var i = 0; i < _manager.Doors.Count; i++)
        {
            if (_manager.Doors[i] == null)
                continue;

            _manager.Doors[i].GetLockState = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Door " + i + " Lockstate", _manager.Doors[i].GetLockState);
        }
    }
}
```

The last script is attached to each door:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System;

public class HoriDoorManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<DoorHori> doors = new List<DoorHori>(); 
    public bool doorLockState;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (transform.parent != null)
        {
            Transform parent = transform.parent;
            var children = parent.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();

            if (children != null)
            {
                foreach (Transform door in children)
                {
                    if (door.name == "Door_Left" || door.name == "Door_Right")
                        doors.Add(door.GetComponent<DoorHori>());
                }
            }
            //ColorDoors(Color.red, Color.green, doorLockState);
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter()
    {
        if (doorLockState == false)
        {
            if (doors != null)
            {
               for(int i =0; i < doors.Count; i++)
                {
                    doors[i].OpenDoor();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void ColorDoors(Color red, Color green, bool state)
    {
        List<Transform> children = new List<Transform>();

        for (int i = 0; i < doors.Count; i++)
        {
            foreach (Transform child in doors[i].GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>())
            {
                if (child == doors[i].transform)
                    continue;

                var renderer = child.GetComponent<Renderer>();
                renderer.material.shader = Shader.Find("Unlit/ShieldFX");

                if(state == true)
                {
                    renderer.material.SetColor("_MainColor", red);
                }
                else
                {
                    renderer.material.SetColor("_MainColor", green);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public bool GetLockState
    {
        get { return doorLockState; }
        set { doorLockState = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

properties are **not serializable**!

those you should never change in editor scripts at all since they are not serialized => never saved and will allways have the default value.

it will **not** work if it is a **property** like

```
public bool GetLockState
{
    get { return doorLockState; }
    set { doorLockState = value; }
}
```

why even use this if your `doorLockState` is `public` anyway??

The problem is that this doesn't mark the changed field `doorLockState` as "dirty".

However you should **not** use `EditorUtility.SetDirty` as suggested by [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55351005/7111561) due to:

> From 5.3 onwards, with the introduction of Multi-Scene Editing, this function **should no-longer be used for modifying objects in scenes**. Instead, you should use `Undo.RecordObject` prior to making changes to the object. This will mark the object's Scene as **dirty** and provide an undo entry in the editor.'

---

Instead in your editor script you have to change the value of `doorLockState`.

If it where `private` you would have to add `[SerializeField]`

```
[SerializeField] private bool doorLockState;
```

But in your case it seems to be `public` anyway so it is automatically serialized.

Than **allways** use proper [SerializedProperty](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedProperty.html) and [PropertyField](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.PropertyField.html) instead of directly manipulate values in editor scripting!

It looks more complex at the beginning but this handles stuff like Undo/Redo and marking stuff dirty (thus saving changes) automatically so you don't have to take care of anything else:

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(DoorsLockManager))]
public class DoorsLockManagerEditor : Editor
{
    private SerializedProperty _doors;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        _doors = serializedObject.FindProperty("Doors");
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        base.OnInspectorGUI();

        for (int i = 0; i < _doors.arraySize; i++)
        {
            var door = _doors.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i);

            // if door == null the script itself has an error since it can't even find the SerializedProperty
            if (door == null)
            {
                EditorGUILayout.HelpBox("There was an error in the editor script!\nPlease check the log", MessageType.Error);
                Debug.LogError("Couldn't get door property", target);
                return;
            }

            if (door.objectReferenceValue == null) continue;

            // FindPropertyRelative seems not to work for MonoBehaviour classes
            // so we have to use this hack around
            var serializedDoor = new SerializedObject(door.objectReferenceValue);

            // If it's public no worry anyway
            // If it's private still works since we made it a SerializeField
            var lockState = serializedDoor.FindProperty("doorLockState");

            // Fetch current values into the serialized "copy"
            serializedDoor.Update();

            if (lockState == null)
            {
                EditorGUILayout.HelpBox("There was an error in the editor script!\nPlease check the log", MessageType.Error);
                Debug.LogError("Couldn't get lockState property", target);
                return;
            }

            // for the PropertyField there is 
            // no return value since it automatically uses
            // the correct drawer for the according property
            // and directly changes it's value
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(lockState, new GUIContent("Door " + i + " Lockstate"));

            // or alternatively
            //lockState.boolValue = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Door " + i + " Lockstate", lockState.boolValue);

            // Write back changes, mark as dirty if changed
            // and add a Undo history entry
            serializedDoor.ApplyModifiedProperties();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

(Ofcourse the value is only updated `OnInspectorGUI` so in case you have multiple Inspector tabs open it is only updated if hovered)

Comment: After the last edit and also before that it's not showing the bools and the "Door" and "Lockstate" not in the editor and not when running the game. It's showing Doors but the list is empty. I removed marked not to use the public bool GetLockState.

Comment: yeah sorry my fault .. apparently `FindPropertyRelative` doesn't work with `MonoBehaviour` only with a "normal" `[serializable] puclic class XY { }` so I added a little "hack" around ;) And another Update: You than also have to call `Update` and `ApplyModifiedProperties` on the `serializedDoor` instead of the `serializedObject`.

Comment: When I put a break point on the line for (int i = 0; i < _doors.arraySize; i++) it's never pass in never get inside the loop. It stop on this line twice then continue without getting inside the doing the code inside the loop.

Comment: The _doors is not null but the arraySize is 0.

Comment: What or how should I set the doors ? In the class DoorsLockManager I didn't change anything there still one line making instance of the doors: public List<HoriDoorManager> Doors = new List<HoriDoorManager>(); and in the script that attached to each door the HoriDoorManager I didn't change either.

Comment: exactly .. you crate only an empty list `Doors` with 0 elements in it. In the Inspector set the size value to whatever size you need and fill the list elements via drag and drop or do it via script e.g. in `Awake` of the `DoorsLockManager`.

Comment: It's working now when running the game. I added awake to the DoorsLockManager and there I Find the "Door" (doors) array loop over it and add the script HoriDoorManager to each of the Doors. But if I want it to work in the editor mode before running the game ? Now I see the checkboxes of each door only when running the game. Should I add in the DoorsLockManager also [ExecuteInEditMode] ?

Comment: Ok adding [ExecuteInEditMode] seems to be working now fine. I can set now the doors lockstate also in the editor before running the game and also while the game is running. Great ! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [EditorUtility.SetDirty](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.SetDirty.html) in **DoorsLockManagerEditor** ?

It seems like editor doesn't keep the initial value.